# SwiftUI view updates

Tags: swiftui

If I have a SwiftUI view that depends on several pieces of external state, there are a number of ways that I can provide it. I'll give an extremely simplified example to illustrate, but in general, the state I'm imagining might be a lot more involved, with many more properties.

I'll ask questions under each approach. I suspect that there might be common answers applicable to all approaches. Also, I might be missing other approaches, which would also be interesting to hear about!

## 1. Multiple bindings:

```
struct QuestionView1: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    @Binding var nickname: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(name)
            Text(nickname)
        }
    }
}
```

- If I only change one property, can the view update more quickly (particularly with a much more complex view than the silly examples here)?
- If I change *both* properties, will I cause *2* updates, and might this end up being slower?
- Is there a way to batch a change of both properties to ensure the view doesn't see two individual changes if I want to ensure they change in-step?

## 2. An `ObservableObject` with distinct `@Published` properties:

```
struct QuestionView2: View {
    
    class Model: ObservableObject {
        @Published var name: String = ""
        @Published var nickname: String = ""
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(model.name)
            Text(model.nickname)
        }
    }
}
```

The questions here are similar to with using `@Binding`:

- Will changing one `@Published` property potentially cause a cheaper redraw.
- Can changing both properties possibly lead to two redraws?
- Can changing both properties possibly cause the view to "see" individual changes and can this be a problem for bits of state that I want to change in-step together?

## 3. An `ObservableObject` with 1 `@Published` state `struct` holding properties:

```
struct QuestionView3: View {
    
    class Model: ObservableObject {
        @Published var state: State = State(name: "", nickname: "")
        
        struct State {
            let name: String
            let nickname: String
        }
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(model.state.name)
            Text(model.state.nickname)
        }
    }
}
```

In terms of "style" alone, I prefer this approach. It seems to definitely let me change all properties in a synchronised way with a single redraw, but it also allows for individual piece of state to change one at a time. However, does this approach lead to potential performance issues because surely there will always be a complete view redraw for any change, no matter how small?

Comment: Synchronously updating multiple properties doesn't cause multiple re-renders. You can test it by putting `print` statement inside `body`

Comment: Thanks @newdev — By “Synchronously” do you mean “just change both properties”, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Yes, I meant, if you changed both properties at the same time